# Multiple endpoint with multiple contracts in WCF

Tags: wcf, wcf-endpoint, servicecontract

Hi I have 2 service contracts IService1 and IService2

I want different endpoints for each service contract also I want to use only basichttpbinding.

Suppose IService1 address is http://localhost:4040/MyApp/Service1.svc then

I want to access IService2 with address http://localhost:4040/MyApp/Service1.svc/service2 or with address other than IService1 address

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you hosting this in IIS ?? If so: IIS dictates your addresses - they're defined as

```
http://YourServer/YourVirtualDirectory/YourService.svc
```

So if you want two separate addresses, you need two separate virtual directories....

Or: **self-host**, then you have full freedom of addresses!

If you self-host, you could definitely define a service (implementing both service interfaces in the same implementation class) that exposes two endpoints:

```
<services>
   <service name="YourNamespace.ServiceImplementationClass">
      <host>
         <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:4040/MyApp/Service1.svc" />
         </baseAddresses>
      </host>
      <endpoint name="Service1"
          address=""
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          contract="YourNamespace.IService1" />
      <endpoint name="Service2"
          address="Service2"
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          contract="YourNamespace.IService2" />
   </service>
</services>
```

So your service 1 would be accessible at the base address defined (`http://localhost:4040/MyApp/Service1.svc`), while your service 2 would be at `http://localhost:4040/MyApp/Service1.svc/Service2`. Is that what you're looking for??